Creating a boxplot of monthly maximum NDVI values from Landsat time series on Google Earth Engine
I'm trying to create a boxplot from monthly maximum NDVI values in my study area from 1984 to 2024 using Landsat data. My idea is to plot the months from January to December on the x axis so the boxes show the monthly NDVI variation across the study period. So far, I have created a Feature Collection containing the maximum NDVI value in my study area for each month and its corresponding date. I haven't been able to calculate the statistics to build the boxes (25, 50, 75 percentiles, max and min values) because the methods for Feature Collections are different from those for Image Collections (used in the sources below).
Is there a way to obtain the statistics from the Feature Collection or to keep the data as an Image Collection? The transformation occurs when I reduce the monthly NDVI images to get the maximum NDVI values inside my study area.
Here is my code so far:
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Initial parameters
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// Location
var studyArea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-68.895, -20.345, -68.795, -20.250]);
// Map.addLayer(studyArea);

// Clouds
var maxCloudCover = 10;

// UI visualization
Map.centerObject(studyArea, 13);
Map.setOptions("SATELLITE");


//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Geoprocessing
//--------------------------------------------------------------------

// Access collections
var L4 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT04/C02/T1_L2");
var L5 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2");
var L7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2");
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2");


// Merge Landsat 4-5-7 collections
var L457 = L4.merge(L5).merge(L7);


// Filter collections by location
var L457_locationFilter = L457.filterBounds(studyArea);
var L8_locationFilter = L8.filterBounds(studyArea);


// Apply scale factors
var landsatScaleFactors = function(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true);
};

var L457_scaled = L457_locationFilter.map(landsatScaleFactors);
var L8_scaled = L8_locationFilter.map(landsatScaleFactors);


// Select and rename needed bands
var L457_renamed = L457_scaled.select(
    ['SR_B3', 'SR_B4'], // old names
    ['red', 'NIR'] // new names
  );

var L8_renamed = L8_scaled.select(
    ['SR_B4', 'SR_B5'], // old names
    ['red', 'NIR'] // new names
  );


// Merge all collections and sort by date
var mergedCollection = L457_renamed.merge(L8_renamed);
var sortedCollection = mergedCollection.sort('system:time_start');


// Filter collections by cloud cover
var cloudFilter = sortedCollection.filter(
  ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', maxCloudCover));


// Compute NDVI over collection
var ndviCollection = cloudFilter.map(function(image){
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['NIR', 'red']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi).select('NDVI');
});
print('NDVI collection', ndviCollection);


// Create months and years lists to iterate on the next function
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(1984, 2024);


// Create an image collection of monthly median NDVI values for each year
var monthlyNdvi = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function (m) {
      return ndviCollection
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
      .median()
      .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).format("MM/YYYY"));
    });
  }).flatten()
);
print('Monthly NDVI', monthlyNdvi);


// Create a feature collection that contains the maximum NDVI value of the monthly median composites
var maxMonthlyNdvi = monthlyNdvi.map(function(image) {
  var maxNDVI = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    geometry: studyArea,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': image.get('date'),
    'maxNDVI': maxNDVI
    // .get('NDVI')
  });
});
print('Max NDVI', maxMonthlyNdvi);

And here is the link to the same code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/79f793e9601a03b220bb3f5723f466b7
The sources I have used are the following:

Spatial Thoughts's boxplot example (GEE charts course): https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?scriptPath=users%2Fujavalgandhi%2FGEE-Charts%3ASupplement%2FBox_Plot_with_Outliers
GEE guides: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_datatable#interval_chart
Google chart guides: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals#box-plot

